# Правильно ли выбран метод решения задачи?

Tags: php

Доброго времени. Для решения задачи по поиску чисел и русских слов, я написал регулярное выражение с ветвлением "|" (или числа, или кириллица). При этом массив совпадений содержит набор данных вперемешку (например, [0]=>111, [1]=>'КИРИЛЛИЦА' etc...). Для разделения чисел и слов я использовал array_walk(), передавая в тело callback функции переменные по ссылке (пример ниже). Верное ли решение я использую? Или такой подход == быдлокод? Спс, ув.

```
$search = '
    qweqweqwe111qweКИРИЛЛИЦАqweqweqwe
    qweqweqwe222qweКИРИЛЛИЦАqweqweqwe
    qweqweqwe333qweКИРИЛЛИЦАqweqweqwe
';

$patt = '~\d{3,}|[а-яё]+~iu';
preg_match_all($patt, $search, $all);

array_walk($all[0], function($i, $k) use(&$numbs, &$words) {
    !($k & 1) ? $numbs[] = $i : $words[]  = $i;
});

// $numbs - массив с числами
// $words - массив со словами
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С использованием именованных групп захвата будет попроще:

```
$patt = '~(?<numbers>\d{3,})|(?<words>[а-яё]+)~iu';
preg_match_all($patt, $search, $matches);

$numbers = array_filter($matches['numbers']);
$words = array_filter($matches['words']);
```

Comment: вы не поверите )) но изначально у меня код так и выглядел (сейчас опубликую в ответе), но из-за пустых значений в результирующих массивах приходилось фильтровать эти массивы (вы кстати, тоже их отфильтровали), и я решил пойти путём НЕ именованных подмасок.

Comment: @Эдуард лучше бы вы пошли путем двух регулярок, одна для чисел, другая для слов, и фильтровать не надо ничего :)

Comment: вот это мне и не даёт покоя - разве две регулярки лучше одной?

Answer (score 0):

Этот код был написан изначально(публикую для @**teran**):

```
$search = '
    qweqweqwe111qweКИРИЛЛИЦАqweqweqwe
    qweqweqwe222qweКИРИЛЛИЦАqweqweqwe
    qweqweqwe333qweКИРИЛЛИЦАqweqweqwe
';

$patt = '~(?P<numbs>\d{3,})|(?P<words>[а-яё]+)~iu';
preg_match_all($patt, $search, $all);

$numbs = array_diff($all['numbs'], ['']);
$words = array_diff($all['words'], ['']);

echo '<pre>'; var_dump(
    $numbs, // массив с числами
    $words  // массив со словами
); echo '</pre>';
```